# offset correct calculation for IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

In my javascript method I have this:

```
if (getInternetExplorerVersion() != '-1') {
        alert("IE!");
        Ice.Menu.showIt(targCompObject.offsetLeft
                + targCompObject.parentNode.offsetLeft,
                targCompObject.offsetTop
                        + targCompObject.parentNode.offsetTop, popupMenu,
                targComp);
    } else {
        Ice.Menu.showIt(targCompObject.offsetLeft,
                targCompObject.offsetTop, popupMenu, targComp);
    }
```

On FF and Chrome the else part is working fine. On IE, I had to change to calculation so now I have the main if... which is still not good.

Do you know any alternative?

UPDATE: Forgot to mention that for IE, the left is correctly calculated but for top it's not.

Temporary work-around (ugly of course) is that I have decreased x number of pixels from teh calculation to fit the position where I want the function to display the popup on IE.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a div with a margin-top and that was the cause of incorrect left offset calculation for IE.

Answer (score 1):

Cant you use conditional stylesheets and change the styles of whatever is not displaying correctly?

```
<!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iefix.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: This js function renders a popup on the position where some div is put. If I change the position of that div I break all the design that's why I prefer js.

Answer (score 0):

You should never do "browser detection" like this. It's a big "no no" in web development, because it leads to many follow-up problems.

Instead, first make sure that your page isn't running in "quirks mode", by checking that your HTML starts with a correct [DOCTYPE](http://www.google.de/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=doctype) and then validate your page and remove all errors: http://validator.w3.org/

If your page then still needs special treatment for IE look up ["feature detection"](http://www.google.de/search?q=javascript+feature+detection) and try to use that to do something else.

(However in your case feature detection may not be the solution. For a more concrete help about this specific problem, we'll need me details: an explanation what "Ice" is, HTML code and/or a running example).